# Adding script to a button which can display Time now

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I am trying to make a spreadsheet with Button formed through shapes (using Drawing tool) and then assign script to it, to track Start time and End time. Basically the two button side by side would say Start and Stop, when you start working, you click the button and the start time would get recorded and when you click the Stop button it would record the time then as Stop time. I was reading the script tutorial and it said that now() argument is not allowed, is there any other way to do this on Google Sheets, because in Excel it is pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script is based on JavaScript : [new Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is the equivalent of `now()`

Your idea is not bad but these button are not fixed, they move with the page whenever you scroll down...

I'd suggest using the sidebar available in new (standard) version of spreadsheets to place your 2 buttons and the corresponding results.

You can use HTMLService or UiApp to build a pretty user interface in the sidebar.

Comment: UiApp was deprecated.